# Word to describe a painting by the materials that were used in its creation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

`Alessandro Magnasco`, `Bernardo Bellotto` and `Claude Monet` are artists or painters.

`Oil on canvas`, `oil on wood`, `oil on paper on canvas`, `oil on card mounted on paperboard`, `oil on canvas on board` are ???.

Source where I found these: https://images.nga.gov

Comment: They are all paintings, irrespective of the material on which they are made.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is "medium". [This explanatory page](https://www.liveabout.com/definition-of-medium-2577638) shows contexts where the medium refers to the binder and the surface. Or more generally, [the Wikipedia page for the list of art media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_art_media) covers more categories of art.

Comment: To fit in the sentence, they are all "media" (slightly sorry to be "that guy").

Comment: @WillCrawford it seems, however, that the plural-of-art (pun unintended but fully acknowledged) in the art world is *mediums,* presumably to avoid confusion with communication media.

Comment: From that page: "To add to the confusion, the term medium is also used to describe the materials an artist uses, or simply the type of paint, such as oil, acrylics, or watercolors, as well the type of support, or surface used for painting. The plural is media. For example, the description "oil on canvas"...